# Under what circumstances would a user/superuser change the permission of a file for its owner?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-metadata

What I understand is, you could change the permission of a file for its owner by, say

```
chmod u=0 file.txt
```

In this case, we removed r, w and x permission for the owner of this file.

But under what circumstances would we like to do that? If you are the file owner, why would you like to downgrade the permission of your own file?

Comment: For the very same reason people use skins for their mobiles. Because you can. Because it protects them from mishandling.

Comment: Thanks Rui! Yeah I later figured out that, I can simply "lock" the file by removing w permission for myself if I would never want to edit it again. That's a use case I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not against an intelligent actor, because as owner, they could chmod() the file any time, giving their permissions back.

It might be useful against programs, if you want to avoid your own programs to play with some of your file on any reason.

However, typically it is more feasible to simply move that file away.

It might be also useful, if the underlying filesystem driver doesn't support chmod(). For example, davfs or vfat file modes are determined by the mount flags and not by the filesystem metadata.